# Root Polylogarithm Dominance Questions

Tags: special-functions, partitions, polylogarithms

Motivation: I am trying to work on a problem related to computing the roots of a certain family of polynomials related to integer partition theory. In particular, I have been trying to ``Bridge the Gap" between the Zero Attractors for the [Partition Polynomials](http://arxiv.org/abs/0711.1373) and the [Plane Partition Polynomials](http://www.emis.ams.org/journals/EJC/Volume_18/PDF/v18i2p30.pdf) by looking at the natural deformation between the two polynomial sequences.  You can see the deformation the zero attractors [on my website](http://www.math.drexel.edu/~dtp29/ExtendedHomotopy.gif) to which I am trying to obtain an analytical description of.

I am trying to prove that if $c_2\approx 1.03$ is the unique solution to $f_1(e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}};s) = f_3(1;s)$ then for $s>c_2,$ and $r\in (0,1),$
$$
f_1(re^{\frac{2\pi i }{3}};s)>f_3(re^{\frac{2\pi i }{3}};s)
$$

Here 
$$
f_k(z;s) = \frac{1}{k}\Re \sqrt[s+1]{Li_{s+1}(z^k)}\quad Li_{s}(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n^s}
$$

I have been thinking about this question for quite some time and haven't found any expression or trick that would make this calculus problem have an elegant solution.  I wanted to know if the MO community had any ideas.